# if I deleted my .ssh folder, is it just a matter of creating a new one?

Tags: ssh

I deleted my .ssh folder, changed my root password, then logged back into my account (mediatemple).

Now I did used the nano command to create the .ssh folder, and inside it the authorized_keys file that will store my public key.

is this correct so far?

Comment: nano is a file editor. You can make directories using the `mkdir` command.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the permissions need to be set correctly if you want authorized_keys to work.

I usually generate a set of keys and have it done automatically. :)

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa
```

fyi; the correct rights are like this:

```
700 on the .ssh directory
600 on the authorized_keys file.
```

Owner is the user.

Answer (score 0):

yes - sounds ok to me